# Retrieving data from existing database and populate it in a listview

Tags: android

I want to retrieve my sqlite data from my database and I want to populate it in a `listview`. I followed an tutorial and implemented the code .I created a database named MYCATEGORY.db and copied it inside my assets folder. But I am getting the exception **"problem copying database from resource file"**.

my main activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DBHelper dbhelper = null;
    private Cursor ourCursor = null;
    private  DBAdapter adapter= null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);      
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbhelper.createDatabase();
        dbhelper .openDataBase();
        ourCursor = dbhelper .getCursor();
        startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
        adapter= new DBAdapter (ourCursor);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class DBAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

        DBAdapter (Cursor c){

            super(MainActivity.this, c);            
        }

        public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {

            DBHolder holder =(DBHolder)row.getTag();
            holder.populateFrom(c,dbhelper);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
            DBHolder holder =new DBHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            return (row);
        }
    }

    static class DBHolder {

        private TextView name=null;
        DBHolder(View row){

            name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }

        void populateFrom(Cursor c,DBHelper r){

            name.setText(r.getName(c));
        }
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_PATH =    "/data/data/com.example.databaseapp/databases/";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "MYCATEGORY.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "MYMAINTABLE";

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "cat_id";
    private static final String  COLUMN_NAME= "cat_name";
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
        this.myContext =context ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {}

    void createDatabase() {

        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB() {

        boolean dbExist =DBExists();
        if(!dbExist ){

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDBFromResource();
        }
    }

    private boolean DBExists(){

        SQLiteDatabase db=null;
        try {

            String databasePath =DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME ;
            db = SQLiteDatabase .openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {

            Log.e("sqlHelpeer ","database not found");
        }
        if(db != null){

            db.close();
        }
        return db!=null ? true :false;
    }

    private void copyDBFromResource(){

        InputStream inputstream = null;
        OutputStream outputstream = null;
        String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH +DATABASE_NAME;
        try{

            inputstream =myContext .getAssets() .open(DATABASE_NAME);
            outputstream =new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);
            byte[] buffer =new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length=inputstream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outputstream.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
            outputstream.flush();
            outputstream.close();
            inputstream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){

            throw new Error("problem copyingg database from resource file");
        }
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        String myPath =DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close(){

        if(dbSqlite != null) {

            dbSqlite.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public Cursor getCursor(){

        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBulider = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBulider .setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME};
        Cursor mCursor =queryBulider.query(dbSqlite, asColumnsToReturn, null, null,         null,null,"cat_name ASC" );
        return mCursor;
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c) {

        return(c.getString(1));
    }
}
```

this is my log cat

```
11-25 14:21:27.095: W/dalvikvm(18936): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c89a68)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936): java.lang.Error: problem copyingg database  from resource file
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at   com.example.androiddatabaselist.DBHelper.copyDBFromResource(DBHelper.java:92)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at    com.example.androiddatabaselist.DBHelper.createDB(DBHelper.java:52)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at com.example.androiddatabaselist.DBHelper.createDatabase(DBHelper.java:45)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at com.example.androiddatabaselist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
11-25 14:21:27.095: E/AndroidRuntime(18936):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check : https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: instead of throwing new error, whold you check what exception your code is throwing by printing e.stacktrace() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your database path. Use this instead

```
ContextWrapper cw =new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
DB_PATH =cw.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/databases/";
```

Or you can use this too

```
String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath() + dbname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DATABASE_PATH` is wrong. It should be an absolute path starting from `/`,

```
DATABASE_PATH =    "/data/data/com.example.databaseapp/databases/"
```

Also you should check if the directory exists before attempting to copy the file. E.g

```
   File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
   file.mkdirs();
   file.mkdir(); 
   outputstream =new FileOutputStream(new File(file, DATABASE_NAME));
```

instead of hard-coding the database path you should use [Context.getDatabasePath(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)), like

```
  mContext.getDatabasePath(mDataBaseName)
```

Comment: ok i edited my package name..but where to add this line mContext.getDatabasePath(mDataBaseName)..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving the wrong database name here DATABASE_NAME= "MYCATEGORY.db" . Please check your database name is "MYCATEGORY.db" or not.